# couchbase email-alert setup using smtp.gmail.com

Tags: smtp, gmail, alert, couchbase, membase

Any one has succeeded setting up Email- Alerts from Couchbase admin for gmail account?

I am having membase cluster installed on EC2. I tried with port 465 or 587 or 25 no success.

The logs shown in UI is not very informative. Can somebody even point me out where to find the detailed log of this alert setup failure?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of Couchbase/Membase you're using?  I can probably answer with that info.  Also, is the SMTP server on EC2, or outside?  As you may know EC2 is a bit of a spam zone to most of the world.

Comment: Its 1.8 Version!. Here the host is smtp.gmail.com. Isn't it the host is the smtp server itself. We don't need to have smtp setup where membase admin is installed. right?

Answer (score 2):

I too was having issues getting the email notifications working in Couchbase with a gmail account. Actually it was a Google Apps account, free edition.

After lots of head scratching the issue turned out to be related to two step authentication. The account I was trying to get it working with had two step authentication enabled.

I tried it with an account that didn't have it enabled and it worked first time.

The settings I used were:

- Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 587
- Username: *Full GApps Email Address*
- Password: *GApps Account Password*
- Use TLS: Checked
- Sender email: Same as Username
- Recipients: Any email address

Cheers, Lee

Comment: Worked for me but i had to generate an app specific password from google.

Comment: I'm not able send test alert it is showing me error and please let me know how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The alerting system has been extended in Couchbase 2.0, leaving a link to the docs here for anyone who might find this question:

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-web-console-settings-alerts.html